# storing the difference of values as changes

Tags: r

I want to store the differences and no differences in values into another dataframe when minusing one dataframe from the other.

For example, given this dataset:

```
> change
   water water2
1      1      1
2      1      2
3      1      2
4      1      1
5      2      2
6      6      4
7      5      4
8      7      5
9      8      9
10     5      5
11     4      2
12     5      5
13     3      3
14     3      3
15     0      2
16     0      0
17     0      0
```

when performing this calculation:

```
water2-water
```

When there is a negative difference, such that `water` > `water2`, assign the value -1. When there is a positive difference, such that `water` < `water2` assign the value 1. Otherwise, if there's no difference, then assign the value 0.

Although, I prefer this to be done when the two dataframes are separate and not in a single data, such that:

```
y2010 <- water2
y2019 <- water
```

I'm working with a larger dataframe, and would prefer to perform a calculation like above and store those differences in a new dataframe.

reproducible example:

```
y2010 <- structure(list(water = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 5, 7, 8, 5, 4, 5, 
3, 3, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L
))

y2019 <- structure(list(water2 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 9, 5, 2, 5, 
3, 3, 2, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sign` function. If the difference is positive it returns `1`, it it's negative it returns `-1`, and if it's `0` it returns 0:

```
df <- data.frame(change = sign(y2019$water2 - y2010$water))

 change
1       0
2       1
3       1
4       0
5       0
6      -1
7      -1
8      -1
9       1
10      0
11     -1
12      0
13      0
14      0
15      1
16      0
17      0
```

Comment: I prefer this for its simplicity

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
#Code
ydiff <- y2019$water2-y2010$water
index <- y2010$water>y2019$water2
index2 <- y2010$water<y2019$water2
ydiff[index]<--1
ydiff[index2]<-1
ydiff[!index & !index2]<-0
#Dataframe
df3 <- data.frame(ydiff=ydiff)
```

Output:

```
df3
   ydiff
1      0
2      1
3      1
4      0
5      0
6     -1
7     -1
8     -1
9      1
10     0
11    -1
12     0
13     0
14     0
15     1
16     0
17     0
```